# Turning a 3D plot to an .obj file

Tags: python, object, 3d

I've been trying to turn a 3d scatter to an .obj file to use it in word. But I cannot do it.

I use the following code:

```
    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10, 10))
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    plt.title("Consumption as labels (Agglomerative)")
    ax.scatter(preprocessed_data[:, 0], preprocessed_data[:, 1], preprocessed_data[:, 2],
                c=predicted_labels, cmap='plasma', linewidth=5)
    ax.scatter(predicted_centers[:, 0], predicted_centers[:, 1], predicted_centers[:, 2],
                c='k', cmap='plasma', linewidth=10)
    pickle.dump(fig, open(r'Results\Expected Consumption (Agglomerative).obj', 'wb'))
    plt.close()
```

However, I try to insert into word I receive the following error:

> obj you're trying to insert was saved with features that aren't supported by office

Do you guys know how to create a file that could work?

Comment: You could use [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/). AFAIK [write_triangle_mesh](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.15.1/python_api/open3d.io.write_triangle_mesh.html) supports `obj` files.

Comment: Could you make an example? Sorry I am not used with any of those libraries